# Asp.Core map encrypted data via PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT from database

Tags: c#, postgresql, cryptography, asp.net-core-2.1

I have web application written in **Asp.Core** 2.1 and **EF.Core** 2.2 connected with **Postgres** database.
I need encrypt any columns in table (not all).

**Problem 1 is:** 
- string data in column must be secured and not readable by human in database table (GDPR).

**Problem 2 is:**
- from application string data in column have to be able to searching/filtering.

I have read a ton of possible solution and I end with:

> The string data in column are encrypted by PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT on database
>   side function which need only passpharse.

But I don't know how I can **map entity property to database and vice versa** with that db encrypt/decrypt function.

I think it is possible with created custom EF.Function extension. But Iam not sure how to use this with EF linq and not raw sql.

Can you give me any advice or get me on the road?

Thank you much